# How can I find the index of the second greatest element in my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, position

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and   I have an array of numbers:

```
[23423, 349843, 13123, 29239, 20201, ...]
```

How can  I find the array index corresponding to the second greatest value in the array?  You can assume that there are at least two elements in the array.

Comment: What should be returned for `[1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: Is the order of values significant? Can the array be sorted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one. `a` is your array

```
a.index(a.max(2).last)
```

Comment: what about `a.index(a.max(2).min)` ?:)

Comment: Yeah, probably better :)

Comment: That gives an unexpected result on `[2, 2]`, does not it?

Comment: Do you mean because greatest and second greatest are equal?

Comment: Yeap. I do not know, what is the expected output in such a case, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [2,3,1,3]
```

**When `3` and `3` are regarded as the two largest values of `a`**

```
def second_largest_not_uniq(a)
  a.each_index.max_by(2) { |i| a[i] }[1]
end

second_largest_not_uniq a         #=> 1 
second_largest_not_uniq [1]       #=> nil
second_largest_not_uniq []        #=> nil
```

**When `1` and `2` are regarded as the two smallest values of `a`**

```
def second_largest_uniq(a)
  a.each_index.uniq { |i| a[i] }.max_by(2) { |i| a[i] }[1]
end

second_largest_uniq [1,3,1,2]     #=> 3
second_largest_uniq [1,1,1]       #=> nil
second_largest_uniq []            #=> nil
second_largest_uniq [1]           #=> nil
```

See [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index), [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) and [Enumerable#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq).

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you need the value

```
value = array.max(2).last
```

Try this if you need the index

```
index = array.each_with_index.max_by(2, &:first).last.last
```

How does this work?

- `each_with_index` creates an enumerator with tuples of `[element, index]`
- `max_by(2, &:first)` finds the two greatest tuples, comparing their first value aka the element
- `last` gets the second-greatest tuple
- `last` unpacks that tuple by getting last value aka the index

Note, this creates `O(n)` temporary arrays though because we chain the `each_with_index` enumerator and I would not use this for large arrays in a performance critical codepath.

Answer (score -1):

I'd sort the array then use something like:

```
ary.size - 2
```

For instance:

```
ary = 5.times.map{ rand(100) } # => [61, 75, 35, 48, 59]

ary.sort # => [35, 48, 59, 61, 75]

ary.sort[-2] # => 61
ary.size - 2 # => 3
ary.sort[ary.size - 2] # => 61
```

> This does not return the index of the element in the original array.

The index of the second largest element after sorting is always `array.size - 2`.

If the array has to be in its original order I'd do this:

```
ary = 5.times.map{ rand(100) } # => [83, 72, 4, 63, 68]
hash = ary.each_with_index.to_h # => {83=>0, 72=>1, 4=>2, 63=>3, 68=>4}
hash.sort[-2] # => [72, 1]
```

At that point `hash.sort[-2]` returns the value and its index in the original array. `72` is the value and `ary[1]` is the index to the value.

Comment: This does not return the index of the element in the original array.

Comment: The index after sorting is always `ary.size - 2`

Comment: Keyword here is "the original array"