# How to return the third largest number in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, while-loop

My code logic to answer a programming question is:

1. Find the biggest number in the input array.
2. Store that number in a new array.
3. Delete that number from the input array.
4. Repeat #'s 1-3 until I have three elements in the new array.
5. Choose the last element of the array to return.

My code is returning three 10's, instead of the three largest elements in the array, 10, 8, and 4. I think it might be because once the inner while loop is done, the code cannot return back to it?

My test code is:

```
puts(third_greatest([8, 1, 10, 4])).to_s
```

My code is:

```
def third_greatest(nums)
  greatest_number = nil
  three_greatest = []

  three_greatest_idx = 0

  while three_greatest_idx < 3
    number_idx = 0

    while number_idx < nums.length
      current_number = nums[number_idx]

      if greatest_number == nil
        greatest_number = current_number
      elsif greatest_number < current_number
        greatest_number = current_number
      end

      number_idx += 1
    end

    three_greatest.unshift(greatest_number)
    nums.delete(greatest_number)
    three_greatest_idx += 1
  end

  return three_greatest
end
```

Comment: How are you handling duplicates?

Comment: This question is effectively a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703164/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-the-second-greatest-element-in-my-array/41705878#41705878).

Answer (score 12):

Once you start to think about solving problems like this the Ruby way, by which I mean leaning more heavily on [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) and expressing your intent as a series of simple operations, often chained together, then the solutions become easier to find.

For example, to find the three highest numbers in an arbitrary Array the obvious solution might be this:

```
def three_greatest(list)
  list.sort.reverse.first(3)
end
```

That sorts the list, which by default is lowest to highest, and then reverses it, making it highest to lowest. The last operation is to copy out the first three entires. This seems pretty reasonable, as it expresses your intent quite clearly and works quite well.

The thing is if you look more closely at the Enumerable offerings there's an even easier solution using [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
def three_greatest(list)
  list.max(3)
end
```

The lesson to learn here is that the Enumerable library, not unlike a mechanic's tool-chest, has a very large number of useful tools. It's important to take some time to at least read through what's in there so you don't end up wasting time re-inventing things that already exist in an elegant form.

In other words, when tackling a problem, check to see if that problems already been solved. In many cases you'll find there's a tool that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Nice. I never noticed the optional parameter for max.

Comment: Very sound advice, thank you. I definitely will check when solving the next problem. The program I am reviewing problems for gave me a constrained set of Ruby information because they claimed that it was all I needed to know in order to complete their coding challenge. But you are right, I shouldn't limit myself and start exploring the world of Ruby more. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, you'll need `list.max(3).last` to answer the question.

Comment: ^ this. This is a great post, throw in an answer.

Comment: @Eric, the optional parameter was added in Ruby v2.2. `min`, `min_by` and `max_by` also got it.

Answer (score 6):

Just to help people understand the difference in performance between `max`, `sort` and not using built-in methods:

```
require 'fruity'

ary = (1..100).to_a.shuffle

def use_max(a)
  a.max(3).last
end

def use_sort(a)
  a.sort[-3]
end

def nth_greatest(nums, n)
  nums = nums.dup # prevent mutating the original array
  result = nil
  n.times do
    idx, max = -1, -Float::INFINITY
    nums.length.times do |i|
      idx, max = [i - 1, nums[i - 1]] if nums[i - 1] > max
    end
    result = nums.delete_at idx
  end
  result
end

compare do
  sorted { use_sort(ary) }
  maxed  { use_max(ary) }
  nth_greatested { nth_greatest(ary, 3) }
end

# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> sorted is faster than maxed by 2x ± 0.1
# >> maxed is faster than nth_greatested by 3x ± 0.1
```

Increasing the size of the array:

```
ary = (1..1_000).to_a.shuffle
```

results in:

```
# >> Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> maxed is faster than sorted by 80.0% ± 10.0%
# >> sorted is faster than nth_greatested by 3x ± 0.1
```

And bumping up the array size again:

```
ary = (1..10_000).to_a.shuffle
```

results in:

```
# >> Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> maxed is faster than sorted by 3x ± 0.1
# >> sorted is faster than nth_greatested by 2x ± 0.1
```

---

> The documentation doesn't mention if max(3) returns a reversed sorted array, even though it looks like it.

The documentation example is:

```
a.max(2) #=> ["horse", "dog"]
```

which is descending, but that's not a good example as it's easier to see using numbers:

```
ary.max(3) # => [100, 99, 98]
```

---

Here are some results using Benchmark to show the baseline speeds:

```
require 'benchmark'

ary = (1..5).to_a.shuffle

10.times do
  Benchmark.bm(4) do |b|
    b.report('sort') { ary.sort[-3] }
    b.report('max') { ary.max(3).last }
  end
end

# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000006)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000004)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000003)
```

And increasing the size of the array:

```
ary = (1..100).to_a.shuffle

# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000020)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000009)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000009)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000010)
```

And:

```
ary = (1..1_000).to_a.shuffle

# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000110)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000057)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000103)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000054)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000101)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000100)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000100)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000100)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000056)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000099)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000099)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000100)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
# >>            user     system      total        real
# >> sort   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000099)
# >> max    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000053)
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) doesn't mention if `max(3)` returns a reversed sorted array, even though it looks like it.

Comment: It does, and you're right, the documentation isn't clear about it.

Comment: Here's the [code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L1433). It does sort `max(n)` before returning it.

Comment: I think you have gone above and beyond the requirements of an answer here. Upvoted for sure. It would be interesting to see if my theory is correct and that the difference would also be negligible if you looked for, say, the 95th largest value out of the 100 value array.

Comment: Take the code and try it and see. I do a lot of benchmark comparisons because knowing how the interpreter reacts to variations in expressions and which methods are faster in given situations results in faster production code where the difference of a 1/10 second makes a huge difference after days of running.

Comment: @theTinMan : Do you have experience with [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity)? I find its result much more readable than Benchmark.

Comment: I use Fruity most of the time but sometimes I need the detail offered by Benchmark. You can see both in the answer. If you search SO for my userid and either "fruity" or "benchmark" you'll find lots of occurrences.

Comment: I messed with your code to run my own tests and found some interesting results. In your final example you are looking for the 5th biggest number out of an array of 1,000. I ran several tests which ran the same test but with an array of 10,000 looking for the nth biggest element, each time the test was run 100 times to measure the average real time of each method, each time incrementing n by 1 starting at n = 1. My conclusion is that in an array of m elements, looking for the nth biggest element, if n > 5% the size of m, the sort method is, in fact, faster. The greater n is, the faster sort is.

Comment: @oMiKeY: It makes sense, because the elements of `max(n)` are themselves sorted before being returned.

Comment: @oMiKeY: Still, the OP explicitely asks for `n=3`, without specifying `m`.

Comment: The documentation about `max(n)` returning a sorted array has been [commited](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/559bef4228eaab3d5493948a87cd84d83e115174) to Ruby repo.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to unset `greatest_number`

```
  nums.delete(greatest_number)
  three_greatest_idx += 1
  greatest_number = nil # this line
end
```

Obviously there is a very simple solution for this in Ruby but I took for granted that you wanted to do it on your own.

Comment: Haha, yes I did want to do it on my own because (as you can tell) I am new to Ruby. Thank you so much, you're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is a task where heavy usage of `Enumerable` module might be not permitted. There are still easier approaches all around. E.g. you do not need to maintain another array: just remove the highest from the original array N times:

```
def nth_greatest(nums, n)
  nums = nums.dup # prevent mutating the original array
  result = nil
  n.times do
    idx, max = -1, -Float::INFINITY
    nums.length.times do |i|
      idx, max = [i - 1, nums[i - 1]] if nums[i - 1] > max
    end
    result = nums.delete_at idx
  end
  result
end

nth_greatest [8, 1, 10, 4], 2
#⇒ 8
nth_greatest [8, 1, 10, 4], 3
#⇒ 4
```

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark all the solutions. I wonder what a a 1-pass solutions with 3 variables would look like. I spent enough time on SO today, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sort it and use Ruby's negative index option for arrays.

```
[8, 1, 10, 4].sort[-3]
>> 4
```

Edit: After many tests I have determined that the sort method shown above is faster than the method below if, when searching for the nth biggest number in an array of m elements, n > 1/20th the size of m. Since in your example we are looking for the 3rd biggest number in an array of 4 elements, and 3 is much bigger than .2, the answer above is significantly more efficient than this alternative method:

```
[8, 1, 10, 4].max(3)[-1]
>> 4
```

Comment: It works, but it's overkill to sort a whole array just to find 3 elements.

Comment: Sure, with 3-element array, it's hard to write an inefficient sorting algorithm. Your sort is applied to N elements though.

Comment: see @theTinMan answer.

Comment: With 5 element arrays the execution speed of `sort` and `max` are barely registering using Benchmark and the fastest bounces around, so using one or the other won't really matter. At 500 elements `max` is barely faster but it's consistent.

Comment: @oMiKeY : This offensive language doesn't belong here. Reading the title, it could be understood that the method should **always** return the 3rd element, but that the array could have any length. In the question, 4 elements are enough to understand the goal, but maybe the method will be used with millions of elements. Talking about big O complexity for 3 elements out of 4 does not make sense.

Comment: If anything, I'm going after the Ruby golden badge. I couldn't care less about comments. I do think StackOverflow is a great place to learn, and I personally really enjoy getting constructive criticism. I don't take it personally when someone tells me something I write isn't optimal. I try to understand why and make it better next time. I didn't mean to offend you. My comment was just to tell you that with 100 elements (which seems reasonable), there's no point in sorting the 97 smallest ones. There's really no need to insult anyone.

Comment: With 4 elements, even bogosort would be fine. When talking about complexity, we're talking about asymptotic behaviour, not 4 or 60 elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134133/discussion-between-eric-duminil-and-omikey).

Comment: 37 downvotes on my answers in 15 minutes, and counting. Who could that be?